# "Not a managed type" error consistently appears when following Spring Boot example project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Refreshing myself on JPA and Spring Boot by following the official docs to create an example project, I'm struggling with a persistent error.

**Employee.java**

```
package payroll;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
class Employee {

  private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
  private String name;
  private String role;

  Employee() {}

  Employee(String name, String role) {

    this.name = name;
    this.role = role;
  }
```

That's the simple entity; it's got a simple constructor, but I trimmed the getters and setters just for display.

**EmployeeRepository.java**

```
package com.example.payroll;

import com.example.payroll.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

Just contains the interface extending JpaRepository.

**PayrollApplication.java**

```
package payroll;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PayrollApplication {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PayrollApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Another simple class, this one generated by Initializr.

**LoadDatabase.java**

```
package com.example.payroll;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
class LoadDatabase {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadDatabase.class);

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initDatabase(EmployeeRepository repository) {

        return args -> {
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Employee("Bilbo Baggins", "burglar")));
            log.info("Preloading " + repository.save(new Employee("Frodo Baggins", "thief")));
        };
    }
}
```

So, this class puts all the pieces together; I'm not configuring a database yet, just preloading with test data. Problem is, I get this consistent error:

`defined in class path resource [com/example/payroll/LoadDatabase.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'initDatabase' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.example.payroll.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.payroll.Employee`

I have tried hardcoding the package to EntityScan, to no avail; I could only place ComponentScan in the application file for this small, simple project, but it's already part of the SpringBootApplication tag.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely related to the fact that the classes are not under the same base package (`com.example.payroll` vs `payroll`). This is the convention followed by Spring Boot by default.

If the main class is under `com.example.payroll`, all classes should be under that package or any sub-package of it (e.g. `com.example.payroll.repository`).

If for some reason the packages need to be different, you should instruct Spring Boot about where to find classes using the `@ComponentScan` annotation.